# Boolean equals method

Tags: java

Writing an abstract class project. Abstract class is the parent class and include a the equals method. Part of my project is to create a Boolean equals method that compares the client IDs (long) of 3 subclasses to make sure that their are not any duplicates IDs. Having an issue implementing the code. Below is what I have so far

```
public static boolean equals(Object A, Object B, Object C) { 
    if(A.equals(B) || A.equals(C) || B.equals(C)) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Need help dropping the 3 class values for client ID into the code and then incorporating the code into a toString() method.

Comment: Please make it understandable for us.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
  
  public static void main(String[]args){
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    long[] array = new long[3];

    
    for (int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
     System.out.printf("Input int number: ");
       array[i] = s.nextLong();
       System.out.println(array[i]);

    }
        // equal(23, array[]);  issue long not long 
    
  }

Comment: public static boolean equal(Object a, long[] b) {
        if (a == null) {
            return (b == null);
        }
        if (b == null) {
            return false; 
        }
        if ((long)a != b.length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            if(a.equals(b[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

Comment: above is the code i have written so far. i am trying to cross reference client ids long variables across 3 child classes that have the same parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your method to the following:

```
public static boolean equals(Object A, Object B, Object C) {
    return A != null && B != null && C != null && (A.equals(B) || A.equals(C) || B.equals(C));
}
```

Few things:

1. Any place you have:

   ```
   if (cond) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
   ```

   You can just return the `cond`: `return cond;`
2. Added non-null validation: `A != null && B != null && C != null`
3. You should override `equals()` method on each class(`A`, `B` and `C`) and include the field/s you want to use in equals (only id in your example)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get what you want, but I'll take a shot:

```
static class Client {
    private long id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        Client oth = (Client) obj;
        return oth.id == this.id;
    }

    Client(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public static boolean equals(Object A, Object B, Object C) {
    return A.equals(B) || A.equals(C) || B.equals(C);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object c1 = new Client(4);
    Object c2 = new Client(3);
    Object c3 = new Client(2);

    equals(c1, c2, c3);
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to implement this code across 3 child classes to cross reference with each other. They all have the same parent class. Would i need to store the number in a array?

Comment: @user9057517, can you be more specific and describe clearer? What number are you talking about? ID?

Comment: For example 
Parent class has private long clientid

Comment: Talking about I'd the program has a abstract parent class that has private string firstname private last name private client ID
The sub classes that inherit the attributes are active clients  inactive clients and I'm working on adding a third class for clients
I need the program to check all of the child classes setClient IDs

Comment: So that I get a true if their are duplicates or a false if their ar not any copy's of the same client id

Comment: If you really want to use equals() in this case, changing if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false; to if (getClass().getSuperclass() != obj.getClass().getSuperclass()) return false; or even removing this line will probably work. However I would've set ID field to protected or used getter and simply compared their ids.

Comment: boolean idEquality(Parent oth) { return oth.id == this.id; } //This will work for all subclasses.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect made private variable static and then used the idEquality